# Finding a programming internship as a high school student

Tags: job-search, internship, united-states

I'm a rising junior (going into 11th grade) and have a great desire to find and participate in a programming internship while I am still at high school. I have a lot of free time during the school year. During summer I am generally free. Grades are not an issue.

I know C++, Java, PHP, and I know some Python/Javascript. Also, I have some experience with reverse engineering using IDA Pro. I have interest primarily in back-end development. I haven't been able to find any opportunities for high school students. The closest offers I found was a front-end development position (I really don't like design), and a tutoring position. If I was only interested in making money, the tutoring position would be fine, however, I wish to have real world back-end development experience.

A big issue with finding a job during high school is legal. For reference, I live in Massachusetts and I am 16 years old, so I am legally allowed to obtain a work permit which doesn't prohibit programming jobs. I'm unsure what to do at this point, as there are no opportunities available in my state involving what I'd like to do.

Has anyone gone through this process? How can I achieve my goal of finding a programming internship?

Thus is not a duplicate of the engineering internship at 16 question because the answers to that question primarily pertain to Engineering, not Programming. Also, the answers seem to all give one answer "networking". I do not really have "networks"/people to contact.

Comment: Do you want an internship or experience? Experience you can get by working on bigger projects by yourself, just find some ideas and start researching and trying backend tecnologies.

Comment: @GrayCygnus Both, I want to work on projects with a company, not by myself.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere I have tried to do so, but their version of "high school internships" is working at Dunkin Donuts or getting an "internship" at an ice cream shop. They don't really have technological opportunities.

Comment: I found [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7604/is-it-futile-to-look-for-an-internship-while-still-in-high-school?rq=1) related question that may be worth reading. Also [this other](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/86614/is-it-appropriate-to-contact-companies-for-a-high-school-internship?rq=1) one

Comment: @GrayCygnus I saw that, I match 1 & 2 and have _some_ contacts (Most of them don't really know job opportunities for programming). Also, I am a US citizen therefore should be no hurdle to hire me.

Comment: Try posting your goal on facebook, linkedin, etc... Network with people in the industry, if you're on the approach you'll probably wind up with an unpaid internship, but it'll fulfill your goal of experience.  Alternatively, you can hop on an open source project or contribute on github, they are not the same as working for a company during an internship however, obviously.

Comment: you  may need to develop what you mean for "backend". usually if it's for web application, you will be asked both front & back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply for engineering internships at 16?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/94685/how-to-apply-for-engineering-internships-at-16)

Comment: This doesn't help you out in the short term (and idk where in MA you are located), but I know in MA there is an AFCEA (lexington-concord) fellowship that has internships for students going into college (recent high school graduates). The requirement is 18yr old, but you can contact them and see if you could be an exception (you could try applying for next summer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an interesting question. I used to hire a lot(!) of college interns, and that might be a viable route. I.e., sign up for some college-level classes (some high schools will let you take them for credit towards graduation instead of your normal courses), then ask the CS or Engineering internship placement office for help.

If that won't fly, reach out to the local startup incubators. You may find an opportunity to invest some sweat equity in one of their ventures. Also try raising your question on Hacker News; there are undoubtedly a lot of people there who might know of an opportunity.

Also do the obvious: look for job listings titled "internship." If you're old enough to work, you're not legally obligated (AFAIK) to reveal your age unless they ask (and if they do, they're taking a legal risk that is off-topic here.) I presume you'll have to stick to part-time opportunities though, which will limit this option pretty severely.

If you've tried the above and it doesn't work, reach out to me directly. I know some people out your way who might be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

Your best approach is networking with friend of your parents and the parents of your friends.

There are quite a bit of "hidden jobs" out there that are gotten through networking with people.  Someone's company might not have an opening right now, but upon hearing an inquiry of "Hey, Bob, my son's friend was wondering if we have any programs for HS kids.  Yeah, he's a programmer"

Another approach is going to a charity or the volunteer office of a local hospital and explain that you want to donate your time as a programmer".

You could also go to a site like gig guru or rat race rebellion and do some independent consulting.